# long.TryParse double values

Tags: c#, parsing

in ASP.NET C#, I'm posting a value and in postback I need to parse it as a long value. well as it looks, values with floating points are treated as non numeric (or at least non long values)
and if the posted value is 50.1

```
long x=0;
long.TryParse(Request.Form["x"], out x);
```

returns 0 that is the default value. but I need to get 50

Comment: It might help you if you actually check the return value of `TryParse` (because that’s the point of it).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is correct that 0 is returned. If you look at [Int64.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx) it states that it only parses integer values. `50.4` is not an Integer value.

Instead you could parse it as a Double and then round it.

```
long x = 0;
Double value = 0;
if(Double.TryParse("50.4", out value))
{
   x = (long)Math.Truncate(value);
}
```

Comment: I know you edited away the `x == Double.NaN` but I just wanted to tell you about something I learned about the hard way. `==` does not work correctly with `NaN`. You need to use `Double.IsNaN(x)` to get accurate results.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks for that - I was answering for speed and remembered that there was a static method for checking. Just wanted to look it up to check before re factoring my answer :)

Comment: "Int64 will accommodate larger values than Double can handle" -- um, no. Max int64: about 9.2e19. Max double: about 1.7e308. Max decimal: about 7.9e28. The downside of double is loss of precision, not range ... there are fewer mantissa bits in a double than in an Int64.

Comment: @JimBalter: Thanks Jim - I have no idea why I put that in my answer back then. You're absolutely right though and I've taken it out of my answer!

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior since 50.1 is not a long value. What you should do is convert it first to Double, then truncate it.

```
double x1, x2;
double.TryParse(Request.Form["x"], out x1);
x2 = Math.Truncate(x1);
```

If you fear the value would be too big to fit in a double, then you'll have to manipulate it as a string.

```
long x;
var splits = Request.Form["x"].Split('.');
long.TryParse(splits[0], out x);
```

Note that I haven't checked if the result of the split is valid or not, but that should get you started.

Comment: I actually thought of that, but I'm not sure if double can have a big value as long can. values might be very big

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - Then you'll need to use it as a string first. Split by "." then parse the appropriate part.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Then use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) instead of double.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani double has a vastly larger range than long, so every long can "fit". But longs >= 2**52 will lose precision; only the top 52 bits will be remembered.